# Append XML file under specified elemnt in PHP

Tags: php, xml, append, appendchild

I have this XML file `Book.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding ="utf-8"?>
<School>
    <Class type="Math">
        <TITLE>Match 101</TITLE>
    </Class>

    <Class type="English">
        <TITLE>English 102</TITLE>
    </Class>

    <Students type="Secondary">
        <Student>
        </Student>
    </Students>

   <Grade>
   </Grade>

</School>
```

and want to add this XML file `edit.xml` under `Students`:

```
<Teachers>

</Teachers>
```

I am using PHP 8.1 and don't know how to do it?

I tried this code but it added at the end of file:

```
$readfile = new class extends DOMDocument {
    public function __invoke(string $path): 
        DOMDocumentFragment 
    {
        return @($_ = $this->createDocumentFragment())
            ->appendXML(file_get_contents($path)) ? $_ : null;
    }
};
$readfile->load(__DIR__ . '/Book.xml');
$readfile->append($import(__DIR__ . '/edit.xml'));
$readfile->save('output.xml');
```

My expected `output.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding ="utf-8"?>
<School>
    <Class type="Math">
        <TITLE>Match 101</TITLE>
    </Class>

    <Class type="English">
        <TITLE>English 102</TITLE>
    </Class>

    <Students type="Secondary">
        <Student>
        </Student>
    </Students>
   <Teachers>

   </Teachers>
   <Grade>
   </Grade>

</School>
```

Comment: Hello. Please. At least tell us what you tried to do?

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054643/php-xml-inserting-a-xml-node-at-a-specific-location

Comment: @Monnomcjo I added my code I tried it but it added at the end of file!

Comment: Can you edit your question and show your **exact** expected output given the sample xml?

Comment: @JackFleeting I edited and I added the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the 'Students' node, so that you can insert the fragment after it.

```php
// bootstrap the target document
$target = new DOMDocument();
$target->loadXML(getTargetXML());
// get an Xpath instance
$xpath = new DOMXpath($target);

// create a document fragment and append content
$fragment = $target->createDocumentFragment();
$fragment->appendXML('<Teachers/>');

// fetch the first 'Students' element
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('(/School/Students)[1]') as $studentsNode) {
    // insert the fragment after it
    $studentsNode->after($fragment);
}

echo $target->saveXML();
function getTargetXML() {
    return <<<'XML'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding ="utf-8"?>
<School>
    <Class type="Math">
        <TITLE>Match 101</TITLE>
    </Class>

    <Class type="English">
        <TITLE>English 102</TITLE>
    </Class>

    <Students type="Secondary">
        <Student>
        </Student>
    </Students>

   <Grade>
   </Grade>

</School>
XML;
}
```

Comment: I tried it but didn't add it the `Teachers` part?

Comment: My example adds the `Teachers` element just after the `Students` element: https://3v4l.org/VO4YB#v8.1.7

Comment: But I want to add `   <Teachers></Teachers>` and I am usning PHP 8.0

Comment: This is just a short tag syntax, it has the same meaning.

Comment: But I tried to add it as I want it gives me an error